# C# Sort Numbers in a list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'll explain my problem with an example: I want to sort the list(0,1,2,6,7) to the list(6,7,0,1,2), so every object in the list, that is say greater than 4 should be sorted in ascending order, beginning with the smallest and then everything that is smaller than 4, in ascending order, beginning with the smallest.

Comment: Looks very similar to rotate items in an array problem.

Comment: are you familiar with lambda expression and `Take()` and `Skip()` also do a google search and show us the code you have tried on your own.. this is not a code service site.

Comment: What should the result be for the input `List<int> list = new List<int> { 0, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 4 };`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this comparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Divider { get; set; }
    public MyComparer(int divider) { Divider = divider; }

    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < Divider && y > Divider) return 1;
        if (x > Divider && y < Divider) return -1;
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

And then you can run this code:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 6, 7 };
list = list.OrderBy(i => i, new MyComparer(4)).ToList();
```

Note it's not clear in the question how you want to handle the value `4` itself, if it should be first entry in the `6,7` group or the last entry in the `0,1,2` group. Based on what you expect to happen, one of the inequality comparison on each `if()` line above should include an `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Doably with linq:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> myList = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 6, 7 };

        var bigger4 = myList           // from myList   
            .Where(item => item > 4)   // filter all bigger 4
            .OrderBy(i => i)           // order them by value ascending
            .ToList();                 // make list to allow AddRange() later

        // I am putting 4rs into this list 
        var smaller5 = myList          // from myList
            .Where(item => item <= 4)  // filter all smalller equal 4
            .OrderBy(i => i);          // order them by value ascending

        bigger4.AddRange(smaller5);    // add to first list

        // output as string with , between values:
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", bigger4)); // which smaller5 added into bigger4
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Or put it in a Extensionmethod:

```
internal static class SillyThing
{
    static public IList<int>
        SortBigger_K_InFrontAnscendingThenAddSmallerEqual_K_Ascending(
            this IList<int> list, int K)
    {
        var biggerK = list
            .Where(item => item > K)   // filter all bigger K
            .OrderBy(i => i)           // order them by value ascending
            .ToList();                 // make list to allow AddRange() later

        // I am putting 4rs into this list
        var smallerK = list
            .Where(item => item <= K)  // filter all smalller equal K
            .OrderBy(i => i);          // order them by value ascending

        biggerK.AddRange(smallerK);    // add to first list

        return biggerK;
    }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
var newList = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,12,14,16,17,192,222,66,44,22,11".Split(',')
    .Select(n => int.Parse(n))
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine( 
   string.Join(",", newList.
        SortBigger_K_InFrontAnscendingThenAddSmallerEqual_K_Ascending(70)));
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Disclaimer:**

@JoelCoehoorn 's method is smater for reusability then using an extensionmethod that is that specific and SILLY.